# What does this expression: void* (*fct)(void*(*)(void*), void*)?

Tags: c, pthreads

I know that e.g.

```
void *(*myFuncName)(void*)
```

is a function pointer that takes and also returns     `void*`.

Is this a pointer which takes 2 arguments?
A `void` pointer another function of that type returning `void*` and a `void*`?
I'm just guessing..

Comment: Apparently it would be a pointer-to-a-function that takes a function-pointer as an argument (if you got everything in the right places).

Comment: If the decl in the title is the actual question, it declares a variable `fct` that is a pointer to a function returning `void *` and taking two arguments: first param is a pointer to a function returning `void*` and taking a single `void*` parameter, second parameter is a `void*`. Assuming the title doesn't change in the next few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

```
void* (*fct)(void*(*)(void*), void*);
```

declare `fct` as a pointer to a function that

- returns a `void *`
- expects its first argument is of type *pointer to a function that expects a `void *` and returns a `void *`* and
- expects its second argument is of type `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   void* (*fct)(void*(*)(void*), void*)
// 44444  2111 333333333333333333333333
```

fct (1) is a pointer (2) to a function (3*) that returns a pointer (4).

(*) The function parameters are `void*(*)(void*)` and `void*`

`void*(*)(void*)` a pointer to a function that takes a pointer argument and returns a pointer

`void*` a pointer

Answer (score 0):

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org) and my compiler both agree. It's a syntax error. There are more close parentheses than open ones.

A function pointer named `x` that returns `void *` and takes two parameters of type `void *` would look like:

```
void *(*x)(void *, void *);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read to the left:

**myFuncName is a pointer**. What is it a pointer to?

Read to the right:

myFuncName is a pointer to **a function which takes two arguments, one of which is a function pointer (with one `void*` argument and returning `void*`, similar to `myFuncName`), and the other one being of type `*void*`, returning `void*`**. What does the function return?

Read to the left:

myFuncName is a pointer to a function which takes two arguments (see above) **and returns `void*`**

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/bill-lynch pointed out, [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void*+%28*fct%29%28void*%28*%29%28void*%29%2C+void*%29) will tell you the same, as long as your syntax is correct.

Best regards
Andreas